# Routes.rb not reflected in _path and _url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've defined custom URL paths in routes.rb, but my `_path` and `_url` helpers produce additional, incorrect routes.

```
routes.rb

get '/:id', to: 'groups#show', constraints: proc {|req| FriendlyId::Slug.where(sluggable_type: 'Group').pluck(:slug).include?(req.params[:id])}, as: :group
get '/:id', to: 'custom_pages#show', constraints: proc {|req| FriendlyId::Slug.where(sluggable_type: 'CustomPage').pluck(:slug).include?(req.params[:id])}, as: :custom_page
get ':group_id/:id', to: 'exams#show', constraints: proc {|req| FriendlyId::Slug.where(sluggable_type: 'Exam').pluck(:slug).include?(req.params[:id])}, as: :exam
```

Expected routes:

- /custom/
- /test/
- /test/exam/

Actual routes:

- /custom/
- /test/
- /test/exam/ (does load, but not defined `_path` or `_url`)
- /exam/ (defined for `_path` & `_url`)

So all the desired routes do load, but the `_path` and `_url` helpers persistently display the wrong path for exam (`/exam/`) despite not being in routes.rb. :/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call these helpers? `exam_path(some_id, group_id:'test')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question is about `exam_path` and `exam_url` route helpers results.
This is probably because of the way you call them.

Since there's additional parameters in path, you should pass them to helper too:

```
exam_path('exam', group_id: 'test') # => /test/exam
```

Comment: Thanks very much Vasfed, this did the trick.  Specifically: `exam_url(exam.group, exam)`